# saving wordcloud plot from AWS lambda to S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am currently trying to save a word cloud I am generating in my AWS lambda function to my s3 bucket, my code executes gut gives  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Body, value: <wordcloud.wordcloud.WordCloud object at 0x7f36643fce10>, type: <class 'wordcloud.wordcloud.WordCloud'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object",

as an error, I have looked online and cant seem to find the cause, do I need to to convert the plot to bytes to be able to store it in S3 like this?

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import boto3

text = "cat cat cat dog dog dog test test hello one two three four five"
generate_word_cloud(text)


def generate_word_cloud(text):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 3000, 
                        height = 2000, 
                        random_state=1, 
                        background_color='salmon', 
                        colormap='Pastel1', 
                        collocations=False, 
                        stopwords = STOPWORDS).generate(text)
    save_to_bucket(wordcloud)


def save_to_bucket(wordcloud):
    #Save tweet list to an s3 bucket
    BUCKET_NAME = "1706224-tweets"
    FILE_NAME = "wordcloud.png"
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    object = s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_NAME)
    object.put(Body=wordcloud)
```

Comment: For uploading image, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619986/uploading-images-to-s3-with-meta-image-jpeg-python-boto3

Comment: i get s3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'upload_fileobj'", is this a python-2 specific function?

Comment: you can refer to aws docs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html or https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.upload_fileobj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I used the /tmp storage from lambda to store the image temporarily, then uploaded the image after

```
wordcloud.to_file("/tmp/"+FILE_NAME)
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file("/tmp/"+FILE_NAME,BUCKET_NAME,FILE_NAME)
```

Comment: I'm getting following error:

[ERROR] ImportError: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /opt/python/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libpng16-39c06ea1.so.16.40.0)





Code:

```lang-python
    wc = WordCloud().generate(' '.join(data))
    
    BUCKET_NAME = "wordcloudkonububu"
    FILE_NAME = "wordcloud.png"

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    wc.to_file("/tmp/"+FILE_NAME)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_file("/tmp/"+FILE_NAME,BUCKET_NAME,FILE_NAME)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could convert the PIL image to a byte array and use that, for instance in your case you could do the following in your `save_to_bucket` method

```py
def save_to_bucket(wordcloud):
    #Save tweet list to an s3 bucket
    BUCKET_NAME = "1706224-tweets"
    FILE_NAME = "wordcloud.png"
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    object = s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_NAME)

    // here you convert the PIL image that generate wordcloud to byte array
    image_byte = image_to_byte_array(wordcloud.to_image())
    object.put(Body=image_byte)


def image_to_byte_array(image: Image, format: str = 'png'):
    result = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(result, format=format)
    result = result.getvalue()

    return result
```